# Can we submit application to applestore by skipping some versions?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

My current application in apple store is with 3.0.1, now to have sync with other platform versions I just wanted to release new version of application with 14.0.1.4. Will it be problem from apple?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah surely you can do this,Apple has no problem at all with this,They just check whether current version is above to the previous one or not.

More information on updating your app(s) can be found on [this Apple Developer page.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ayan Khan, Can you please provide apple documentation link for the same?

Comment: I have provided the link for versions,but that not contains the statement to skip versions,I am telling you my personal experience as i did same 2 times.So no problem with that.......:)